Godot Engine. Transferring data between scenes
The enemy should always follow the player, which means taking his positions, but since I have an enemy and the player I have these scenes, I can't extract the player's position as I did in the screenshot:
enter image description here
How to do it right?

Please provide your code as text by wrapping it like this: ```<your_code_block_here>```. Check out the markdown editing page for more details.

The reason Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

maybe this will help?

@M.R.M. thank you very much
